# Detect if page if component is loaded first time angular 6

Tags: angular

Hi is there any way to detect whether component is loaded first time in angular 6
I want to run a function call only is the component is loaded for the first time else show the old variable data

Comment: Can you add some details to make this an answerable question. For example, what do you specifically mean by "first time"?

Comment: What's wrong with the constructor function ?

Answer (score 2):

You can probably leverage `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` for this.

Something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('yourComponentNameLoadedAlready')) {
    // branch that this component has already been loaded
  } else { 
    // branch that this component is loading for the first time, set the session storage key to 'yes' to tell you this component has already loaded.
    sessionStorage.setItem('yourComponentNameLoadedAlready', 'yes');
   // continue doing what you want to do for first time load.
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

`localStorage` has a similar API but its storage is more permanent.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a nice way to do this using `previousNavigation` from the [Router.getCurrentNavigation() method](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#getcurrentnavigation)

This returns `null` if there is no previous navigation.

What's not mentioned in the docs though is that `Router.getCurrentNavigation()` only works when used in the `constructor` of the class.

```js
export class SomeComponent  {
  hasPreviousNavigation;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
  ) {
    this.hasPreviousNavigation = Boolean(this.router.getCurrentNavigation().previousNavigation);
  }
}
```

`previousNavigation` is of type `Navigation`

```js
type Navigation = {
    id: number;
    initialUrl: string | UrlTree;
    extractedUrl: UrlTree;
    finalUrl?: UrlTree;
    trigger: 'imperative' | 'popstate' | 'hashchange';
    extras: NavigationExtras;
    previousNavigation: Navigation | null;
};
```

I wrote about this in this short article [Angular: Determine previous page URL](https://dev.to/cogoo/angular-determine-previous-page-url-3kh9)

Answer (score 0):

The **localStorage** object stores data with no expiration date. The data will not be deleted when the browser is closed, and will be available the next day, week, or year and The **sessionStorage** object stores data for only one session (the data is deleted when the browser tab is closed), so you can't check properly if your component has executed for the first time and the value of variable won't clear for next time your component executes. I think it's better to use a global service because with every refresh your variable would set. 
Your service can be something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalSettingsService {

  private _yourComponentNameLoadedAlready:boolean;

  constructor() { }


  public set YourComponentNameLoadedAlready(v : boolean) {
    this._yourComponentNameLoadedAlready= v;
  }

  public get YourComponentNameLoadedAlready() : boolean {
    return this._yourComponentNameLoadedAlready;
  }


}
```

//Your component

```
constructor (private globalSettingsService:GlobalSettingsService){ 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  if (this.globalSettingsService.YourComponentNameLoadedAlready) {
    //This component has already been executed

  } else { 
     //This is the first time that this component executes
     this.globalSettingsService.YourComponentNameLoadedAlready=true;

  }
}
```